# Way to check if calling shared_from_this() is valid?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'd like to use `shared_from_this()` to get a `std::shared_ptr` from an object that was passed by reference. However, I'd like to be robust to objects which might not be in a shared pointer, or which might not even be dynamically allocated.

Is there a way to check if a given object (inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this` and passed by reference) is managed by a shared pointer prior to invoking the potentially undefined behavior of calling `shared_from_this()`?

Comment: You can't. In addition it seems that you have a mistake in your design if you need to do this.

Comment: @t.niese: you can... see the answer by David Schwartz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own `make_shared`, `shared_from_this`, and `enable_shared_from_this` that has whatever semantics you want. Implementing the semantics you ask for is not difficult:

1. The class should hold a `weak_ptr` to the instance of the class it's templated on.
2. The `make_shared` implementation should initialize the weak pointer from the `shared_ptr` it creates first.
3. The `shared_from_this` should attempt to lock the weak pointer and return an empty `shared_ptr` if it fails.

Alternatively, if `weak_from_this` is available on your platform (it's a C++17 feature), you can just use that.

But, as others have said, it seems very hard to believe that this really is the best solution to whatever problem you're having. The cases where you need `shared_from_this` to work would have to perfectly align with the cases where `shared_from_this` will work. It's hard to imagine a use case where that's the case.

Comment: Plus one, trying to lock the weak pointer is the way to go. Bu t fot that you do not need your own implementation, one can also use `weak_from_this` in `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: If your platform has `weak_from_this`, yeah. Updating.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware that it's a C++17 feature.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, constructors are hidden behind factory methods, so that you can't create objects directly.
This definitely solves the problem. Here a minimal example:

```
#include <memory>

struct S: public std::enable_shared_from_this<S> {
    static std::shared_ptr<S> create() {
        return std::shared_ptr<S>{new S};
    }

private:
    S() { }
};

int main() {
    auto ptr = S::create();
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, if you need to know whether a class is managed by a `shared_ptr` or not, it probably indicates an issue in your design.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to make the copy constructor private?

Comment: @t.niese Sure, actually you should make private all the constructors (default, copy, move, custom, and so on). That's what is called a *minimal example*.